# Passing shibboleth sp attributes to application on Jetty with Apache as proxy

Tags: apache, spring-boot, jetty, shibboleth, mod-proxy-ajp

I have a few spring boot applications running on Jetty embedded.
And I have Shibboleth SP running on Apache server.

I am able to pass assertion attributes to Tomcat via AJP, but, since Jetty9 doesn't support AJP anymore, I can't do the same.

I want to know how to configure Apache, so the assertion attributes may be passed to application running on Jetty.

```
<Location /myapp>
        SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
        SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
        AuthType shibboleth
        ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
        require valid-user
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Attributes need to be coded as headers by apache2 with the

```
ShibUseHeaders On
```

directive in your location.

Please have a look of all the implications from the [Shibboleth Official Documentation](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPJavaInstall.).